# How to Decompress memorystream using SevenZip C#

Tags: c#, 7zip, sevenzipsharp

I'm using the below code to compress the stream using SevenZip, and it produces an output which I write back into filesystem.

```cs
private static byte[] Compress(byte[] input)
{
    var inputStream = new MemoryStream(input);
    var outputStream = new MemoryStream();

    Int32 dictionarySize = 1 << 16;
    string matchFinder = "bt4";
    Int32 numFastBytes = 128;

    CoderPropID[] propIDs =
    {
        CoderPropID.DictionarySize
        ,CoderPropID.MatchFinder
        ,CoderPropID.NumFastBytes
    };

    object[] properties =
    {
        (Int32)(dictionarySize)
        ,matchFinder
        ,(Int32)(numFastBytes)
    };

    SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder encoder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Encoder();
    encoder.SetCoderProperties(propIDs, properties);
    encoder.WriteCoderProperties(outputStream);
    outputStream.Write(BitConverter.GetBytes(inputStream.Length), 0, 8);
    encoder.Code(inputStream, outputStream, inputStream.Length, -1, null);
    outputStream.Flush();
    outputStream.Close();

    return outputStream.ToArray();
}
```

But when I try to DeCompress the output file, using below code it throws error

> System.OverflowException: 'Array dimensions exceeded supported range.

at line `coder.SetDecoderProperties(properties);`.

```cs
private static void DecompressFileLZMA(string inFile, string outFile)
{
    SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder coder = new SevenZip.Compression.LZMA.Decoder();
    FileStream input = new FileStream(inFile, FileMode.Open);
    FileStream output = new FileStream(outFile, FileMode.Create);

    // Read the decoder properties
    byte[] properties = new byte[5];
    input.Read(properties, 0, 5);

    // Read in the decompress file size.
    byte[] fileLengthBytes = new byte[8];
    input.Read(fileLengthBytes, 0, 8);
    long fileLength = BitConverter.ToInt64(fileLengthBytes, 0);

    coder.SetDecoderProperties(properties);
    coder.Code(input, output, input.Length, fileLength, null);
    output.Flush();
    output.Close();
}
```

I'm not able to find out what is incorrect in `SetDecoderProperties`?

Comment: Never used 7Zip, but you're only writing 3 properties in your encoder, and yet reading 5 in your decoder. Is that right?

Comment: Possibly the decoder doesn't need as many parameters as the encoder, but the use of a hard-coded 5 constant for determining the number of bytes to read seems hack'ish to me.

Comment: A lot of the examples I saw used a check like `if (input.Read(properties, 0, 5) != 5) throw (new Exception("input .lzma is too short"));` - perhaps you could too.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, I have tried these examples as well, but getting the same error. I'm setting dynamic array(with different datatypes) in encoder and trying to read the same in decoder but error remains the same